# ValueError during сonver str to datetime.date problem

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I get the entry date in the format "2020-12-23", type - string. I have to compare it to the current date and run the if/else condition.

code.py

```
curent_date = datetime.date.today()
csv_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(csv_date, type(csv_date))
print(curent_date, type(curent_date))
if csv_date > curent_date:
    date_error.append
```

get me

```
2029-12-24 <class 'datetime.date'>
2020-04-04 <class 'datetime.date'>
```

But after I get **500 error**

> Exception Value: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

What's the problem?

Comment: Does value come from a csv file? It seems like you have missing (empty) values. You should have a look at the `pandas` library that will help you handle both datetime values and missing values.

Comment: yes data come from csv, you're right, the problem is with the empty field. Thank you!

Comment: print out the contents of value before the date convertion, chances are there is a value in your csv in the wrong format

Comment: I added a check with the condition if. The problem is solved.